# Remove all non-latin passages from a string with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to remove all passages that contain non-latin characters from a string however unlike a lot of answers I have seen, I want to also remove the punctuation in those passages while leaving the same punctuation in English passages.

To say it in another way, when a non-latin character such as "ָהּ" is encountered, the regex will start skipping everything including ascii punctuation until an [a-zA-Z] character is found.

I have tried the following example but its incorrectly removing the quote after "halves" leaving me to believe I don't have a good definition of non-latin characters.

`[\u0250-\ue007][^a-zA-Z]*`

Here is an example of input text (updated):

```
or perhaps, a - אוֹ דִילְמָא אֵין אִשָּׁה מִתְקַדְּשֶׁת לַחֲצָאִין כְּלָל (12);time
תֵּיקוּ
person cannot be in separate halves at all, even
though both "halves” would come together simultaneously?(13)
The speaker replies:(14)
```

and the resulting string is:

```
or perhaps, a - time
person cannot be in separate halves at all, even
though both "halveswould come together simultaneously?(13)
The speaker replies:(14)
```

As you can see, it messes up on the third line. Obviously, I could just exclude that particular character but I'm worried it will mess up on other edge cases.

Any other ideas? (I'm working with Javascript btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that by "*a non-latin character such as `הּ`*" you mean **any non-ASCII *letter***.

To match any letter other than an ASCII letter, you can use `[^\P{L}a-zA-Z]`. This is a negated character class that matches any chars other than a non-letter char (`\P{L}`) and ASCII letters (`a-zA-Z`). So, it is basically the `\p{L}` pattern with the exception of ASCII letters.

This Unicode character class based pattern requires a `u` flag, supported by Node.js JavaScript environment.

The solution will look like

```
text = text.replace(/[^\P{L}a-z][^a-z]*/gui, '')
```

Note the `g` flag makes `replace` replace all occurrences in the string and `i` is used to shorten the ASCII letter pattern (since it makes the pattern matching case insensitive).

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = `or perhaps, a - אוֹ דִילְמָא אֵין אִשָּׁה מִתְקַדְּשֶׁת לַחֲצָאִין כְּלָל (12);time
תֵּיקוּ
person cannot be in separate halves at all, even
though both "halves” would come together simultaneously?(13)
The speaker replies:(14)`;
console.log(
  text.replace(/[^\P{L}a-z][^a-z]*/gui, '')
)
```

Output:

```
or perhaps, a - time
person cannot be in separate halves at all, even
though both "halves” would come together simultaneously?(13)
The speaker replies:(14)
```

Comment: looks good! that solved the issue